# Parsing email with content instance of base64decoderstream

Tags: base64, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

My application polls a specific email account and downloads email attachments to disk.
I am able to successfully handle inline email attachments and outline attachments as parts (Part instanceof javamail Part).

But, there's one specific email wherein it has an attachment that is of type `com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream`.

Hence, I am not able to fetch the file name or its inputstream. 
Although, i can see the fileName in original message headers.

Following is the snapshot of the headers:

```
    Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2013 13:05:29 -0400
    From: SXXXXX <SXXXXX@XXXXXXn.com>
    Subject: PO 926460
    Message-ID: <ADR38000000849147@prd410.gleason.com>
    X-Brightmail-Tracker: H4sIAAAAAAAAA+NgFtrIKsWRWlGSWpSXmKPExsVy7Ey1ju7lL4ZBBp/nqVlsbr3K5MDosXdD
H3MAYxSXTUpqTmZZapG+XQJXRs/Cz2wFM64zVexdsIO5gXHDOaYuRk4OCQETib975jFD2GIS
F+6tZ+ti5OIQEjjGKLF3+VR2COc0o8SRNwsYQapYBLQl7nRuYgOx2QR0JOb8a2UHsYUFpCTa
Lq8FmyoioCHRuvk/2FReASOJV1ueQdmCEidnPmEBsTkFhCQ6rnaywmyesO4XM8R8Z4m316+B
7RISsJS40zyVDaJGU2LGgRtgu5gFbCWOfpkGZStKTOl+CGWrSazqWMg+gVFoFpJ1s5C0zELS    
    Content-Type: application/pdf; name="PO 926460.pdf"
    Content-Description: PO 926460
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: FANUCEXCHCHI03.FAC.local
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
    X-TM-AS-Product-Ver: SMEX-10.0.0.1412-7.000.1014-20144.004
    X-TM-AS-Result: No--7.671100-5.000000-31
    X-TM-AS-User-Approved-Sender: No
    X-TM-AS-User-Blocked-Sender: No
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: SMEXr^dE;1027300;0;This mail has
    been scanned by Trend Micro ScanMail for Microsoft Exchange;
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
    MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Please assist, how to fetch the filename and get input stream and thus save it to disk as file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no attachment in that message.  It's a single part (as opposed to multipart) message of MIME type "application/pdf".  Since a MimeMessage is-a Part, just treat it the way you do an attachment Part.

Comment: I tried treating it as Part. I used getFileName() and getInputStream() method of http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html but both the parameters were null. I feel i need to parse the headers to fetch the file name when i get the Message content as com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream and somehow get this decoded stream converted to a file. The email has a pdf attachment.

Comment: I was able to fetch the file name successfully by casting the message object to MimeMessage and thus was able to save the attachment to disk. Thanx